# RuntimeError in PinsController#index: declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding, pins

While working on my rails app I created a "Pins" scaffold using the following command in my terminal:

> rails generate scaffold Pins description:string --skip-stylesheets

This creates the scaffold in my applications and then I run:

> rake db:migrate

and it goes through without a hitch. I didn't alter any of the generated pages but when I finally try to access the new scaffold on localhost:3000 is gives me the following error:

> RuntimeError in PinsController#index
>
> In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level
> Rails.root: /Users/code/appname
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:6:in `index'

I've been following a video tutorial to create my app and the issue didn't come up with the user in the video. I'm trying to figure out the issue using online resources but nothing is solving my problem.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow. I totally misunderstood your question. Yes it is. https://github.com/KinanAlhoch/valingo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the top of your controller you'll need to add:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  ...
end
```

You can read more about this mime-type on the [API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks. Any clues why `rails generate scaffold` would create "broken" code. Shouldn't that line be added automatically?

Comment: what version of rails is everyone running into this issue?

Comment: I just had it with rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

paste config/application.rb

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```

it works!